# TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of 'null'

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx, calculator

I'm attempting to create a simple Javascript Calculator locally in react.  My code so far is below, and the error that I'm running into is the following:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
App
src/App.js:6
  3 | 
  4 | function App() {
  5 |   const calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator')
> 6 |   const keys = calculator.querySelector('.calculator__keys')
  7 | 
  8 |   keys.addEventListener('click', e => {
  9 |     if (e.target.matches('button')) {
```

**I'm looking for some insight as to why `querySelector` is coming up as null.  Or more specifically, why `'.calculator'` and `'.calculator__keys'` are not providing any information for the `querySelector` function.  Could this be a problem related to my CSS, or is there a Syntax Error that I'm not aware of within my code?**

[This is my updated GitHub repo in case you would like to take a look at my CSS as well.](https://github.com/blakelucey/js_calc)

```
import './App.css';
import './calculator.css'

function App() {
  const calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator')
  const keys = calculator.querySelector('.calculator__keys')

  keys.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.matches('button')) {
      const key = e.target
      const action = key.dataset.action

    if (!action) {
      console.log('number key!')
    }
    if (
      action === 'add' ||
      action === 'subtract' ||
      action === 'multiply' ||
      action === 'divide'
    ) {
      console.log('operator key!')
    }
    if (action === 'decimal') {
      console.log('decimal key!')
    }
    if (action === 'clear') {
      console.log('clear key!')
    }
    if (action === 'calculate') {
      console.log('equal key')
    }
  }})
  return (
    <div className='calculator'>
    <div className='calculator__display'>0</div>
    <div className='calculator__keys'>
    <button id='add'className='key--operator' data-action='add'>+</button>
    <button id='subtract' className='key--operator' data-action='subtract'>-</button>
    <button id='multiply' className='key--operator' data-action='multiply'>&times;</button>
    <button id='divide' className='key--operator' data-action='divide'>÷</button>
    <button id='seven'>7</button>
    <button id='eight'>8</button>
    <button id='nine' >9</button>
    <button id='four' >4</button>
    <button id='five' >5</button>
    <button id='six' >6</button>
    <button id='one' >1</button>
    <button id='two' >2</button>
    <button id='three'>3</button>
    <button id='zero' >0</button>
    <button id='decimal' data-action='decimal'>.</button>
    <button id='clear' data-action='clear'>AC</button>
    <button id='equals' className='key--equal' data-action='calculate'>=</button>



    </div>
    </div>
)}
export default App;
```

Your help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the React.js world, I understand that you are quite new to React, but you better understand core concepts of components (lifecycles, props, state and etc.). The error you see is not React or CSS related, as it explains itself it will be `null` if there is no element with classname `calculator__keys`. So, you first have to check if it is not `null`. Please read and research React fundamentals first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses virtual DOM, while you are rendering the component, there is no Real DOM so there is nothing to select. You can use `useRef` hook to select elements.

For example ;

```
function App() {

const calc = useRef(null)

 return (
    <div ref={calc} className='calculator'> )
}
```

In this case, `calc.current` will be the selected element. Please log to the console and examine yourself.

Comment: Are you saying that `calculator` should then read `const calculator = document.querySelector(calc.current)`? Also, If I changed the syntax of the component from `function App() {` to `class App extends React.Component { constructor(props){ super(props)} ` and then add `render() {` before `return` would that be beneficial in this instance?  Thank you.

Comment: @BlakeLucey No, useRef returns an element object which has  a current property. So in this code calc.current is the element with calculator className. You don't use querySelector since it refers to the Real Dom, there is nothing in real dom so you won't be able select with that. It's unnecessary to use class component while you can use Hooks.

Comment: Okay, so `calc.current` will replace `querySelector` so `const calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator')` will become `const calculator = calc.current` and I will have to follow the same process for `const keys = calculator.querySelector('.calculator__keys')` but with a different variable to refer to my `calculator__keys` `<div>`.   Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to set up as I showed, also you should import useRef from react.